# HTML select Tag Title using Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter 3.
The countries select box is an optional field on a form:

```
<select name="countries">
    <option>Choose a Country</option>
    <option value="en">England</option>
    <option value="fr">France</option>
    <option value="de">Germany</option>
</select>
```

I have the following line for the countries field validation:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('year',  'Year',    'trim|integer');
```

When I submit the form with the 1st option (Choose a Country), even without a value defined the validator sees something like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->input->post('year'));
echo '</pre>';

>> Choose a Country
```

.. when I am expecting something like false or null.
How can I make CI ignore the value when there isn't one selected?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Disable the first option. `<option value="" disabled>Choose a Country</option>`

Comment: Are you sure to use year validation for countries?

Comment: It's irrelevant. I've removed it from the code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you paste the wrong line, I think it should be `countries` instead of `year`.

You can make it by these ways:

1. Give the default selection a value, that can be caught. And handle when the value equals to `none`

```php
<select name="countries">
    <option value="none">Choose a Country</option>
    <option value="en">England</option>
    <option value="fr">France</option>
    <option value="de">Germany</option>
</select>
```

2. Change your validation rule that only allows options in the list. If the value returns isn't in the list, it would make error.

```php
$this->form_validation->set_rules('countries',  'Countries',    'required|trim|in_list[en|fr|de]');
```